# Understanding a basic SQL query

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery

I have a query like

```
SELECT tran_number
  FROM table_a WHERE customer_id IN
          (SELECT customer_id 
             FROM table_b
            WHERE customer_key = 89564
                  AND (   other_phn_area_code
                       || other_phnum_pfx_num
                       || other_phnum_sfx_num IN
                          (123456789)))
       AND phn_area_code || phnum_pfx_num || phnum_sfx_num IN (123456789)
```

---

The above code is working fine. The concern is with the inner query (copied inner query alone below)...

```
(SELECT customer_id 
                 FROM table_b
                WHERE customer_key = 89564
                      AND (   other_phn_area_code
                           || other_phnum_pfx_num
                           || other_phnum_sfx_num IN
                              (123456789)))
```

When i execute this query, i'm getting error as `customer_id: invalid identifier`. In real, `table_b` is not having any field named `customer_id`. If so, then how it is working, without any issue, when i use it as an inner query above.

Please help me to understand this.

***Database details below***

```
Oracle 11G Enterprise edition 11.2.0.2.0
PL/SQL Release 11.2.0.2.0
```

Comment: What do you mean by "The above code is working fine." - it returns you some output, but what do you exactly want to achieve with this query? You're trying to get tran_number from rows whose customer_id satisfies - what?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a matter of *scope*.  Oracle validates identifiers starting with the innermost sub-query and working outwards.  If we add table aliases to your original query things might become clearer:

```
SELECT t1.tran_number 
  FROM table_a t1
  WHERE t1.customer_id IN 
          (SELECT t1.customer_id  
             FROM table_b t2 
            WHERE t2.customer_key = 89564 
                  AND (   t2.other_phn_area_code 
                       || t2.other_phnum_pfx_num 
                       || t2.other_phnum_sfx_num IN 
                          (123456789))) 
       AND t1.phn_area_code || t1.phnum_pfx_num || t1.phnum_sfx_num IN (123456789)
```

In effect, the outer query is using the sub-querty as a test for EXISTS, i.e. just checking for the existence of a given value of CUSTOMER_KEY and those other columns. If this is not what you want then you should change the column name in the sub-query.   (And that's a pretty good bet: you're probably getting puzzling results from the main query and that's why you're investigating the sub-query in isolation).

Using aliases in these scenarios is always good practice.  If you had aliased the sub-query like this:

```
....
  WHERE t1.customer_id IN 
          (SELECT t2.customer_id  
             FROM table_b t2 
            WHERE t2.customer_key = 89564 
....
```

the error would have been immediately apparent.

---

The SQL Reference does explain the operation of scope in sub-queries, but it's hard to find.   What [it says](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries007.htm#i2067858) is this:

> "Oracle resolves unqualified columns in the subquery by looking in
>   the tables named in the subquery and then in the tables named in the
>   parent statement"

You can find a clearer explanation of scoping in the PL/SQL documentation;  SQL sub-queries work in the same fashion.  [Find out more](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/fundamentals.htm#i15754).

Answer (score 7):

if the `where` condition of that inner select has a result, then the column `customer_id` from `table_a` will be selected. 
If not then it won't be selected. The outer select checks that with the `in` condition. That is like saying: "Only return something if the inner select return true."

Answer (score 0):

Thats is a known bug with IN. If you use table alias you will get error

```
SELECT tran_number 
  FROM table_a WHERE customer_id IN 
          (SELECT b.customer_id  
             FROM table_b b
            WHERE customer_key = 89564 
                  AND (   other_phn_area_code 
                       || other_phnum_pfx_num 
                       || other_phnum_sfx_num IN 
                          (123456789))) 
       AND phn_area_code || phnum_pfx_num || phnum_sfx_num IN (123456789)
```

Also use EXISTS to avoid this type of silent behaviour

```
SELECT tran_number 
  FROM table_a as t1 WHERE EXISTS  
          (SELECT *
             FROM table_b as b
            WHERE customer_key = 89564 
                  AND (   other_phn_area_code 
                       || other_phnum_pfx_num 
                       || other_phnum_sfx_num IN 
                          (123456789))
        AND b.customer_id  =t1.customer_id) 
       AND phn_area_code || phnum_pfx_num || phnum_sfx_num IN (123456789)
```

Comment: I don't think it's right to describe the correct action of the scoping rules as a "bug".  More properly, scope allows us to introduce our own bugs if we don't pay attention.