# Strange SQL execution result in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery

```
select unique owner 
from all_tables 
where sysdate-50 < (select last_analyzed from dual);
```

I just wrote above code and it is strange the result is different with below code.

```
select unique owner from all_tables;
```

However if I execute (`select last_analyzed from dual`) separately, an error will pop up.

I am confused how the result is generated.

Comment: What is the error that you are getting?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Understanding a basic SQL query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11518475/understanding-a-basic-sql-query)

Comment: LAST_ANALYZED is a column present in the subquery context (ALL_TABLES system view) not in the DUAL system table. Great APC! +1 to you

Answer (score 2):

Your query has an unnecessary subquery. This is equivalent:

```
select unique owner from all_tables T
where sysdate-50 < T.last_analyzed;
```

Comment: +1 but this doesn't execute unless I remove the 'as'

Comment: Thanks. I never use `AS` myself but couldn't remember if Oracle required it or not. Fixed.

Answer (score 2):

It's taking the `last_analysed` as a column from `all_tables`, since there isn't such a column in `dual` - it's an effect of scope, I suppose. It's clearer if it's written with an alias:

```
select unique owner
from all_tables t
where sysdate-50 < (select t.last_analyzed from dual);
```

You don't need the subquery at all, you can just do:

```
select unique owner
from all_tables
where last_analyzed >= sysdate-50;
```

(which I suspect is the wrong way round; if you're looking for stale stats I assume you want `< sysdate-50`).

Answer (score 0):

last_analyzed is one of the columns of all_tables that has date value. You can not run the subquery alone